# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_saved_in_db' Fastapi Tortoise(orm)

Tags: tortoisesvn, fastapi

Getting this error while performing API request.
Here's the models.py

class UserModel(models.Model):

```
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    email = fields.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    full_name = fields.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = fields.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        table: str = 'users'
```

class project(models.Model):

```
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    project_name = fields.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    user_id = fields.ForeignKeyField(
        "models.UserModel", related_name="items", null=True)
```

router.py

from models import users

@auth_router.post("/add_project")

async def register(form_data: users.project = Depends()):

```
    project = await users.project.create(project_name=form_data.project_name,user_id=1)
    await project.save()
```

Just wanted to post data with foreign key. But it is not allowing. Help needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In this section of the documentation (https://tortoise.github.io/models.html#the-db-backing-field), it describes that you append '_id' to the field name.

Here is how you would fix it:

```
class project(models.Model):

    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    project_name = fields.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
    user = fields.ForeignKeyField(
        "models.UserModel", related_name="items", null=True
    )
```

You would just use 'user', because tortoise will append '_id' to any ForeignKeyFields.

Another way you could fix it (probably not what you want):

```
project = await users.project.create(project_name=form_data.project_name,user_id_id=1)
await project.save()
```